# Advanced Theme support

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony

I have to implement an ability of using themes. I tried https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle and it works.
But because i'm using multisite feature (i.e. site_id is being defined depending on domain name) the paths should be like these:

1. app/sites/{site_id}/Resources/themes/phone/BundleName/template.html.twig
2. app/sites/{site_id}/Resources/BundleName/views/template.html.twig
3. src/BundleName/Resources/themes/phone/template.html.twig
4. src/BundleName/Resources/views/template.html.twig

And if i request `::template.html.twig` paths would be:

1. app/sites/{site_id}/Resources/themes/phone/template.html.twig
2. app/sites/{site_id}/Resources/views/template.html.twig

So the questions are:

1. The site_id only can be fetched when runtime `$container->get('engine.site')->getId()`. I tried to get inside the Liip\ThemeBundle\Locator\FileLocator's constructor and tweak `$this->path` there to be able to get a path for different sites of a view `app/Resources/sites/{site_id}/` (but would be super to get `app/sites/{site_id}/Resources/`). But this way we of course will get an error when first request and the cache is not formed yet (`«Whoops, looks like something went wrong. InactiveScopeException: You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").»`). And every other request will work out normally. But this is really not a solution. **From this the question is where can i dynamically build paths for templates?**
2. all the themes in LiipThemeBundle can be set up in config. **But how do i make this list dynamically (all themes we can fetch with `$container->get('engine.site')->getThemes())`?**

Answer (score 0):

LiipThemeBundle creates parameters liip_theme.file_locator.class which holds the name of the class (with locator).

So we have to change this parameter in our bandle's DI to the name of our class. And its description is quite simple:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Bundle\EngineBundle\Locator;
use Liip\ThemeBundle\Locator\FileLocator as BaseFileLocator;

class MultisitesFileLocator extends BaseFileLocator
{
    public function locateAppResource($name, $dir = null, $first = true)
    {
        $container = $this->kernel->getContainer();
        if ($container->getParameter('engine.dir_sites') !== '') {
            $dir = $container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/' .
                   $container->getParameter('engine.dir_sites') .
                   $container->get('engine.site')->getId() . '/Resources';
        }

        return parent::locateAppResource($name, $dir, $first);
    }
}
```

However multisite feature doesn't work this way...
But it's not a big deal.